# multi select value checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

guy's i need help i made a code for get the item value of checkbox
but why that's cant be running well?
is there any wrong in my code?

this is my jquery code for do multi select value

```js
//for get the checkbox data (my data from database)
$(document).ready(function() {
 $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  url:"../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php",
  success: function(data){
   var list = JSON.parse(data);
   for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
   var $chk = $('<input type="checkbox" name="chk_'+ list[i]['nama']  +'" />'+ list[i]['nama']  +"<br />");
      $("#multiselect").append($chk);
   }
   return false;
  }
 });
});
// this function for getting the value. but it cant work, i dont know why
$('#ok').click(function() {
    var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
    }).get();
    
    $("#nama_check").val(sel);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

i give the html too when it need
here the html

```html
 <div id="myMd5" class="md5">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="md5-content">
  <div id="cont-body" class="cont-body">
  <div class="multiselect" id="multiselect" style="margin-left:65px">
    
 </div>
  <input type="button" name="ok" id="ok" class="ok" value="Pilih" style="margin-left:170px"/>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to put your `$('#ok').click(function()` inside`$(document).ready(function()`?. Sorry I can't comment because I have a low reputation

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#ok').click(function() {
        var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
        return $(el).val();
        }).get();

    $("#nama_check").val(sel);
    })

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"../php/absen/absen_karyawan_autocomplete.php",
        success: function(data){
            var list = JSON.parse(data);
            for(var i=0; i < list.length; i++){
            var $chk = $('<input type="checkbox" name="chk_'+ list[i]
            ['nama']  +'" />'+ list[i]['nama']  +"<br />");
            $("#multiselect").append($chk);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: `$(document).ready(function()` just for calling the checkbox data. not for calling the data to get the value.
i separate that.

Comment: @MinervazMine please check